# Deleting a lex bot and all associated aliases

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-lex

I'm trying to delete an AWS lex bot. The prerequisite for the delete it action is that all associated aliases should be deleted. I'm deleting these aliases sequentially as the API doesn't support parallel delete. I'm certain that the first alias is deleted but when the command to delete the next alias is issued, it errors out saying there's already a delete operation taking place.

Comment: *"saying there's already a delete operation taking place"*... please don't paraphrase error messages.  Is the code for the error a `ConflictException` or something else?

Comment: That's correct. I get a ConflictException and I'm assuming it's because the previous delete operation hasn't ended although I get a response before I initiate the current delete.